# Create an overload set class relying on std::invoke with classical overload resolution rules

Tags: c++, overloading, c++17, template-meta-programming, perfect-forwarding

I would like to design a class:

```
template <class... F> class overload_set;
```

that will take a list of callables at construction, and will have an `operator()` that will apply the classical overload resolutions rules to decide which function to call.

For two functions, this would be something like this:

```
template <class F0, class F1>
struct overload_set: F0, F1
{
    constexpr overload_set(F0 f0, F1 f1): F0(f0), F1(f1) {}
    using F0::operator();
    using F1::operator();
};
```

However, this would only work with function objects, while I would like it to work with any callable working with `std::invoke` (free functions, functors, lambdas, functions members, members...). And I would like it of course, to work with all the subtelties of the ref/const qualification of function members like in:

```
struct subtle
{
    constexpr void operator()() noexcept {}
    constexpr void operator()() & noexcept {}
    constexpr void operator()() && noexcept {}
    constexpr void operator()() const& noexcept {}
    constexpr void operator()() const&& noexcept {}
};
```

If `subtle` is passed to `overload_set` it should work well.

Is it possible to create such a class `overload_set` in C++17, and if so how (with as much template metaprogramming tricks as required, but as little C macros as possible (hopefully none))?

Comment: For function objects, functors and lambdas your approach should already work. For functions, you could create a simple wrapper class template that provides an `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing what @KerrekSB said

```
template<typename F>
struct functor
{
    using type = F;
};

template<bool Noexcept, typename R, typename... Args>
struct functor<R (*)(Args...) noexcept(Noexcept)>
{
    struct fn
    {
        R (*p)(Args...) noexcept(Noexcept);
        R operator()(Args&&... args) const noexcept(Noexcept)
        {
            return p(std::forward<Args>(args)...);   
        }
    };
    using type = fn;
};

template<typename F>
using func = typename functor<std::decay_t<F>>::type;

template<typename... Fs>
struct over : func<Fs>...
{
    template<typename... Gs>
    over(Gs&&... gs) : func<Fs>{std::forward<Gs>(gs)}... {}

    using func<Fs>::operator()...;
};

template<typename... Gs>
auto makeover(Gs&&... gs)
{
    return over<func<Gs>...>{std::forward<Gs>(gs)...};   
}
```

You use it as

```
int main()
{
    auto o = makeover([](int){ std::cout << "int\n"; }, 
                     +[](double){ std::cout << "double\n"; });
    o(42);    // prints int
    o(42.0);  // prints double

    auto o2 = makeover(+[]() noexcept {});
    std::cout << noexcept(o2());  // prints 1
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50f327ce7c626d34)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the fix. Although, I still don't understand why it was ambiguous.

Comment: Actually, I got it now. The hidden conversion on `this` apparently plays the same role in overload resolution as a conversion on a parameter